# Python Requests login: i have error 403 but the request looks correct

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to login into [www.zalando.it](http://www.zalando.it) using the requests library, but every time I try to post my data I am getting a 403 error. I saw in the network tab from Zalando and the login call and is the same. These are just dummy data, you can test creating a test account.

Here is the code for the login function:

```
import requests
import data
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


home_page_link = "https://www.zalando.it/"
login_api_schema = "https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login/schema"
login_api_post = "https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login"

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.zalando.it',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection' : 'close',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}


with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)

        r = s.get(home_page_link)

        # fetch these cookies: frsx, Zalando-Client-Id
        cookie_dict = s.cookies.get_dict()
        # update the headers
        # remove this header for the xhr requests
        del s.headers['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests']
        # these 2 are taken from some response cookies
        s.headers['x-xsrf-token'] = cookie_dict['frsx']
        s.headers['x-zalando-client-id'] = cookie_dict['Zalando-Client-Id']
        # i didn't pay attention to where these came from
        # just saw them and manually added them
        s.headers['x-zalando-render-page-uri'] = '/'
        s.headers['x-zalando-request-uri'] = '/'
        # this is sent as a response header and is needed to
        # track future requests/responses
        s.headers['x-flow-id'] = r.headers['X-Flow-Id']
        # only accept json data from xhr requests
        s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'

        # when clicking the login button this request is sent
        # i didn't test without this request
        r = s.get(login_api_schema)

        # add an origin header
        s.headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.zalando.it'
        # finally log in, this should return a 201 response with a cookie
        login_data = {'email:': data.email,
                      'request': data.request,
                      'secret': data.secret}
        r = s.post(login_api_post, json=login_data)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.headers)
```

I also used fiddler to try to sniff the data traffic but the HTTPS request is not performed and the latter generates the following exception:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.zalando.com', port=443) : Max retries exceeded with url: /api/login 
(Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en /1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', 
SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)'))))
```

For the HTTP request instead I get a 301 error

Comment: According to your error, it seems like you're using a proxy. Did you remove that part of the code? It seems important to understanding how to fix the problem.

Comment: that's just what i don't understand, i'm not using any kind of proxy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75275395/20443541) helps you.

I think youru website might detect, if a request gets sent with javascript.